# Airflow config from Vault secrets not working

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, hashicorp-vault

I have an Airflow application running in kubernetes along with Vault. I am already using Vault to manage certain Airflow Connections and it's working fine (which proves the connectivity with Vault is working fine).

I am now trying to configure Airflow's configs `core.sql_alchemy_conn`, `celery.result_backend` and `celery.broker_url` through Vault as mentioned [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html?highlight=_secret#envvar-AIRFLOW__-SECTION-__-KEY-_SECRET).

In my `values.yaml` I have

```yaml
secrets_backend_kwargs:
  auth_type: 'kubernetes'
  kubernetes_role: 'role-id'
  connections_path: 'applications/secrets/airflow/connections/'
  config_path: 'applications/secrets/airflow/config/'

config:
  core:
    sql_alchemy_conn_secret: "sql_alchemy_conn"
  celery:
    broker_url_secret: 'broker_url_conn'
    result_backend_secret: 'result_backend_conn'
  secrets:
    backend: 'airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend'
    backend_kwargs: '{{ .Values.secrets_backend_kwargs | toJson }}'
```

In my vault, I have the proper encoded URI (`postgresql%2Bpsycopg2%3A%2F%2Fblahblahblah...`) stored at the right location:

[image]

Now when I deploy the application, `run-airflow-migration` job fails with AirflowConfigException while validating the configs.

```
# AirflowConfigException
error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor
```

Which means it is not picking the postgres database connection settings from Vault and using sqlite settings from Airflow configs.

I also tried this by providing these configs in the variables for the containers.

```yaml
env:
  - name: VAULT_ADDR
    value: 'https://path.to.vault/'
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET
    value: 'sql_alchemy_conn'
  - name: AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL_SECRET
    value: 'broker_url_conn'
  - name: AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND_SECRET
    value: 'result_backend_conn'
```

I can see these environment variables in the container but the deployment fails because of the error in migration job.

I verified the Vault path and connectivity by changing the `config_path` in the secret backend kwargs and if I change that I still reach the Vault but since the key/connection id doesn't exist on the incorrect path so I get error from Vault. Which means that When I am setting the `_secret` as config, application is reaching Vault to fetch value but not updating or using the value.

I can't figure what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configs are set like Variables in the secret backend, while I was setting them like a Connection with `conn_uri` as key.

It is not clear in the official Documentation and had to go through the code to find the fix.

So after putting my configs in correct way (where mount point is `secret` and `config_path` is `applications/secrets/airflow/config/`), it worked.

```
vault kv put secret/applications/secrets/airflow/config/sql_alchemy_conn value=postgresql://user:pass@host:5432/db
```

Comment: Just wondering - is that documentation not  "good" https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp/stable/secrets-backends/hashicorp-vault.html. Maybe (as someone who had pain with finding out) could contribute back some improvements there ? It's very easy "Suggest a change on this page" button at the bottom.

Comment: Will definitely do!